# Looking for jazz tracks that use the trombone and the tuba

Tags: jazz, playlists

I intend to collect few tracks/songs/pieces where specific instruments stand out and it is catchy enough that I can remember it so when I hear the instrument again, I can identify it. Ive made a really big list and the only instruments I'm missing out are the trombone and the tuba. So I searched for this in Classical and Romantic, and it doesn't seem like Classical and Romantic place trombones and tubas as the fronters very much.

So, I'm looking for catchy jazz tracks in which trombone and tuba standout (if possible, those that employ liberated dissonance too).

Comment: This type of question with a potentially extremely long list of answers and no 'correct' answer doesn't fit this sit so well. Listen to almost any big-band recording ever made and you'll hear trombone solos. Tuba solos are rarer.

Comment: Exaclty @PiedPiper, So since Tuba Solos are rarer, that restricts the List from getting extremely long

Comment: The list would still be long

Comment: finding: Tuba plays at the starting of Miles Davis - Godchild

Comment: There's plenty of tuba all through "Birth of the Cool"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tuba_players has some jazz players

Comment: Yup, @PiedPiper, Bill Barber was a member of Mile Davis' nonet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're teaching yourself to identify instruments according to their sound. In that spirit, here's an answer toward that end.

Try searching for music by brass ensembles, concert bands, and brass bands. These cut across all musical genres and feature trombones and tubas prominently.

A few suggestions to get you started, with links to one video of each.

- [Canadian Brass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5YqXjsJAI0) ("Flight of the Tuba Bee")
- [Empire Brass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKcx9n9t9js) ("Ain't Misbehavin'" and "When the Saints Go Marching In" -- both jazz)
- [Dirty Dozen Brass Band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASGn9H5fdPM) ("My Feet Can't Fail Me Now" -- jazz)
- Example of a [Trombone Concerto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBVU_ejKHfI) (by Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov)
- Example of a [Tuba Concerto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GzEvWXN3zY) (by Ralph Vaughan Williams)

Answer (score 2):

You can start with these stylistically very diverse tuba solos:

- Mattis Cederberg "[Tangerine](https://youtu.be/Kvflefgi030)"
- New Bumpers Jazz "[Doctor Jazz](https://youtu.be/He1IG8AlsNA)"
- Bob Stewart "[First Line](https://youtu.be/DlZrKi_zXmE)"

Comment: +1 for sharing some deep cut ones, I'm not sure why it's not letting me upvote you answer.

Comment: But in other SE sites you can vote and comment without fulfilling rep requirements if the answer is under your own question right?

Comment: @RishiNandha_M It's the same on all the sites: 15 to vote up, and 50 to comment on other people's posts. You can always comment on your own.